# "Your java version is out of date" with latest java

Tags: java, macos, applet, java-8, osx-yosemite

I have the latest java by now 1.8.0_25 on my mac. version checker says it's fine. 
But I 'm getting this error [image: "Your java version is out of date"]

If I click 'Later' it works, but then appears again later. I see this almost since the release of 1.8.
I also have jdk1.7 and 1.6(apple) installed. enter image description here

[image: update screen]

[image: Installed versions]

Comment: Is it installed at the correct place? Some applications have the weird behaviour on OSX that it looks for apples older Java installation, or for Oracles - but not both.

Comment: It's an applet.. correctly signed. Running in Safari. Version checker on java.com says it's the latest version. Java console also shows correct and up to date version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same problem for the longest time. No old Java VM showed up in the system preferences. I eventually found and old JDK in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines.

Check in the following locations for "old" VMs:

```
find /Library -name '*java*'
find /System/Library -name '*java*'
find ~/Library -name '*java*'
```

Comment: how is it the accepted solution, what to do when I find TOO MANY files in above locations?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, a newer JDK does not necessarily replace an older JRE. So it might be that you have the latest JDK, but still an old JRE somewhere. Go to the Apple menu and choose "System Preferences…". There should be a "Java" entry in the last section. Clicking on it should open the Java Control Panel in a separate window.

Check what it says there in the Update-tab. My guess is, that there is still an older version listed. So I would just update it. You can also check if on the "Java" tab in the Control Panel, if there are multiple versions listed and which one is the top one. Maybe reordering them if you have multiple to have the newest on top might help as well.

Comment: It says I have the latest version. As I said version checker on java.com shows I have everything up to date